# how to set up correctly RecyclerView and Database?

Tags: android

I am faced with a task: I created a database (it is in the photo below) and I want in the android application using RecycleView to create elements in the application, that is, CardView in which there will be a title, a photo, a description from the database and a button with the background from directly drawable . If not difficult, you can explain how to implement it.

[image]
[image]

I tried a bunch of manuals, but did not find a similar.

My current code:

```
package com.ru.testonline;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    FirebaseFirestore db =FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    DocumentReference mMainRef =db.collection("Interface").document("Menu");

    RecyclerView rv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rv = findViewById(R.id.rv);
        final LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);

        mMainRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                Log.d(TAG, "doc" + document);
                if (document.exists()) {
                    List<String> menu = (List<String>) document.get("Card_1");
                    Log.d(TAG, "Menu: " + menu.size());
                    if (menu.size() != 0) {

                    }
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });


 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using FireStore. It is very easy.

You need to follow these simple steps
1. Read Data
2. Add to the List of your Adapter
3. Notify the adapter that list is changed

**Here is a sample code for this.**

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();


db.collection("products").get()
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                if(!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()){

                    List<DocumentSnapshot> list = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();

                    for(DocumentSnapshot d : list){

                        Product p = d.toObject(Product.class);
                        productList.add(p); //adding read data to your list 

                    }

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //notifying the adapter that list is changed

                }


            }
        });
```

If you want to see a step by step detailed explanation you can follow this video: **[Firestore Android Tutorial - Reading Data](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWEfGZeDuAY&list=PLk7v1Z2rk4hhN_d5e1ACuhVNrTDOew66L&index=2)**

Answer (score 0):

You require a RecyclerView.Adapter to push all your items into, from there you will create a ViewHolder for your cell, inflate and link the view to the viewholder on onCreateViewholder and update your data on onBindViewholder

Then on your fragment with your recyclerView you need to create an adapter once using the standard CustomRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new CustomerRecyclerViewAdapter(listOfItems) and then link the adapter to your recyclerView with recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: If it's not difficult, you can show how it looks in android studio, just did not work with RecyclerView earlier and do not quite understand